# how does terraform handle updating/deleting resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

I am switching to gitlab and plan to use terraform. I have used cloudformation before and understand , deploying stack to aws, creating change stack and updating resources. how does updating/deleting work in terraform.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how it works?

Answer (score 2):

Its similar to CFN. TF has a [state](https://www.terraform.io/language/state) file (can be local or remote) where it stores information about your currently deployed resources and their configuration.

After any changes to your TF config files, TF would create a [plan](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/plan) of how to apply your changes in relation to what it has in the state. The plan is similar to changeset in CFN, it will show what resources have to be deleted, replaced, created or modified.

Just like with changeset you have option to review the plan and if you agree with a proposed actions, you can [apply](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/apply) it.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is what happens if there is a failure. Cloudformation will rollback the stack to the previous state whereas Terraform will leave the resources in a partially deployed state.